# Do I need to use SyncAdapter for my app?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-syncadapter

I am making a social media Android app. The user will require to sign up or login the first time he opens the app. Now, obviously, I want to store that login information so the user doesn't have to login everytime he starts the app. I could simply store login details in SharedPreferences but I have heard about SyncAdapter and that's the primary purpose of SyncAdapter(also for background sync). I don't need background sync. How would SyncAdapter work? Since, I am using a Java Server to save data on online database, how can I configure Java server to for oAuth of whatever is required. I **do not** want to access data from other networks(Facebook, Twitter, etc). I want the user to sign up using email, username and password. Nothing else is required. Is SharedPreferences a better option?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save login details of user in `SharedPreferences` What you can do is that let user login to your server and when login is successful return a `token` to android app. Save that token to the `SharedPreferences` then you have to check in `sharedPreferences` if there is a valid token. If there is valid token then let user use app if `token` is invalid or `null` redirect user to login screen.
I hope this will help you somewhat.

**Update**
You can use JWT tokens. Here is a useful resource for that https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/.  You need to explore REST API with JWT Auth flow.

Comment: It kinda does help me. How can I check the validity of the token? Is there a standard way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are quiet a lot of questions you are asking here.

> 1st: Save login state such that you don't ask user to login again.

Yes, you can do this in `SharedPreferences`

> 2nd: How would sync adapter work?

The developer site talks about this very clearly. You can have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html).

> 3rd: How can you configure your app to call java server?

You could simply use `AsyncTask` and invoke the API. Or for better performance and error free calls you can use `Retrofit`

I hope my answer helped.

Comment: How to store the login information in SharedPreferences was my question. Saving username and password is obviously not safe. I know how to use AsyncTask for HTTP connection, my question was how to send tokens or use oAuth on my server.